# cloud computer minimum machine count in production mode

Tags: server, architecture, production-environment

for production mode is it always recommended to use minimum 2 server?
because 1 server could crash. The load is always within the green range.

Thx

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the requirements. How much downtime is allowed? In many cases it is OK to wait a few seconds until a new container is started. In other cases you can't even alow a few seconds and have to run a hot stand-by in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Put 2 or more and a load balancer in front of it, or 3 containers or more. It will prevent downtime. How @lexicore pointed out, it depends on your requirements. Maybe a few minutes out of service is not a big deal, maybe it is.